# update html binding after each change in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm trying to make typing animation using typescript that append next character from string every 200ms.

i read alot of solutions that talk about zone and ChangeDetectorRef but nothing work.

the problem is the whole string is shown after finish the process showing the final result (no animation :( )

> Edit :
>
> i'm using Angular 2.

this is my simple app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = '';
  nots="app works!";

constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){
  setTimeout(() => {


  this.sleep(200);
    this.title='a';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

     this.sleep(200);
    this.title+='a';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

      this.sleep(200);
    this.title+='a';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

      this.sleep(200);
    this.title+='a';
    this.ref.detectChanges();

      this.sleep(200);
    this.title+='a'; 
    this.ref.detectChanges();

    console.log(3);
 }, 1000);    
}

 sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
}
```

you can see i want to show aaaaa like this :
a aa aaa aaa aaaaa . any help ?

Comment: Even you put multiple `this.ref.detectChanges()`, they are just being put into a queue like space and wait for the current method to finish. So simply put, multiple detectChanges() get called after this method. Also you `sleep` method is sync/blocking. Its net effect is same as the last `this.ref.detectChanges()`. That is to say, you will only see the whole string. Plus, if you remove  this.ref.detectChanges();, it still works since angular calls it anyway...

Comment: so what is the correct way to do ?

Comment: demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pkbhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: perfect answer thanks .
put it as answer to rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach that you might want to try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
  ngOnInit() {
    interval(500)
    .pipe(
      take(5)
    )
    .subscribe(_ =>
      this.name += 'a'
    );
  }
 }
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pkbhk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Alternatively, you can still use plain old promise appraoch, which sticks more closely to your original approach,

```
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  import { interval } from 'rxjs';
  import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';


  @Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title = '';
    ngOnInit() {

      this.sleep(200)
        .then(() => this.title = 'a')
        .then(() => this.sleep(200))
        .then(() => this.title += 'a')
        .then(() => this.sleep(200))
        .then(() => this.title += 'a')
        .then(() => this.sleep(200))
        .then(() => this.title += 'a')
        .then(() => this.sleep(200))
        .then(() => this.title += 'a')

   // same as 
  /*  let promise: any = this.sleep(delay)
      .then(() => this.title = 'a');

    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      promise = promise
        .then(() => this.sleep(delay))
        .then(() => this.title += 'a')
    } */
    }

    sleep(milliseconds) {
      let resolve;
      let promise = new Promise((_resolve) => {
        resolve = _resolve;
      });
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds);
      return promise;
    }
  }
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8ur5y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts